# Functions and concavity

Tags: functions, optimization

If $f$ is concave, and $f(1)=2$ and $f(6) = 12$, what is the smallest possible value of $f(4)$?

How do I test this without the function?

Comment: What is the definition of concavity of a function that you know? Write it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the minimum value directly from the definition of concavity in the form

$$f((1-t)x+ty)\geq (1-t)f(x) + tf(y) \text{ for all } t \in [0,1]$$

Now, for $x=1$ and $y=6$ you get from $4 = (1-t)\cdot 1 + t\cdot 6$

$$t = \frac 35 \Rightarrow f(4) \geq \frac 25 f(1) + \frac 35 f(6)=8$$

The minimum value, hence, is $8$ which is reached if $f$ is a linear function $(f(x)= mx +c)$.

Comment: I now understand! Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The "smallest" concave function will be affine i.e. of the form $$f(x)=ax+b.$$. So, find $a,b\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $f(1)=2$ and $f(6)=12$.